# Davis formula application

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, simulations, drag

So I stumbled upon the Davis formula for trains while doing some researches about my project but I don't know how to apply it (programmatically) :

Let's say for example this variant :
$$R'=1.3+\frac{29}{w}+.045v+\frac{.0005av^2}{wn}$$

Where -$R'$ is the rolling resistance in lb/ton, $w$ is the axle weight in us-tons,
$v$ is the speed in mph, $a$ is the cross-sectional variable in square feet and $n$ is the number of axles in car.

1. I want to know how to convert the result from lb/ton to Newton?
2. I also want to know if I should apply this formula to the locomotive of the train and add it to all the other cars of the train then sum the result?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what the "Davis formula for trains" *is*, and give us a reference to where you found it?

Comment: okay so here is the thing, i'm currently a student and working on a train simulator project as an intern, the problem is that i'm not familiar with physics and i don't even know from where to start, the formula i found originate from here [link] (http://www.elvastower.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=82501) and it is used to calculate the rolling resistance of the train, i honestly just want to simulate using c# a basic and correct behavior of the train to accelerate and brake for the meantime.